# Read txt file into list Python

Tags: python, list, file, element

I am using this code to read a text file into a list.

```
with open("products.txt", "r") as f:
    test=f.read().splitlines()

print(test)
```

The resulting output is:

```
['88888888,apple,0.50', '99999999,pear,0.20', '90673412,orange,1.20']
```

I need the output to look like below so I can reference the individual elements.

```
['88888888', 'apple', '0.50', '99999999', 'pear', '0.20', '90673412', 'orange', '1.20']
```

Comment: It looks like you are reading csv data. You can use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module for that.

Comment: You have a CSV file not just a text on e look at libraries to parse those

Comment: What's the input file look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension :

```
with open("products.txt", "r") as f:
    test=[i for line in f for i in line.split(',')]
```

Or use `csv` module to refuse of splitting the lines :

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('products.txt') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        test=[i for row in spamreader for i in row]
```